# Trying to export values from datfiles to csv

Tags: python, csv, export

I am trying to export some values on a csv file. I run the below code :

```
import glob
import csv

lines=[]

files = glob.glob('*#*')             
for file in files:
    with open(file,'r+') as f:
        first_line = f.readline()
        lines.append(first_line[28:39])

print(lines)
```

Ready code that I found to export to csv. not totally correct for sure. I don't need the loop I think (for val..)

```
with open("test.csv", "r+") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
         for val in lines:
    writer.writerow([lines])
```

The problem I am facing is that due to the fact I store the values on a list. So they are exporting in the csv a bit messy. Is there any way to export them in the second column of the excel and on the first add the name of the files?

My files have names like (0116,0216,0316 etc)

I know that it would be useful to work with pandas, because I am working with data files and Excel. However I am not familiar with pandas atm so another way might be useful too.

I am adding two screenshots that might help

[image: the files that I read have the below input and i retrieve the first row and the second column number in our example the value "1660195"]

[image: the files are general files with just txt input]

So I want to export "1660195" in the second column of the csv that i export. and in the first column I want the name of the file . for example

[Screenshot1 the input]

[Screenshot2 the files]

[image: the output csv should be like that]

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question, but you should be using `csv.reader()` to read the contents of the file, not just using it to write output.

Comment: Actually, no, I don't understand the question at all. Please clarify the format of the file you're reading in

Comment: @Panagiotis, can you show the sample data and show what is desired output ? i can check with pandas solution..

Comment: hello guys please check above i edited  my OP

Comment: @PanagiotisIoannidis, do you want to extract any particular column data?

Comment: @pygo yes i want to extract the 2nd collumn/1st row (1660195 )

Comment: @PanagiotisIoannidis You are reading lines from .png files?

Answer (score 0):

hello i actually tried pandas and the output is ok.

```
import glob


import pandas as pd

lines=[]

files = glob.glob('*#*')             
for file in files:
    with open(file,'r+') as f:
        first_line = f.readline()
        lines.append(first_line[28:39])



df = pd.DataFrame(lines)
df.to_csv('tst.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create dataframe in pandas directly from your datafle and try something like this..

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':list('ABC')}, index=[0,2,1])
>>> df
  foo
0   A
2   B
1   C
>>> df.loc[df.index[0], 'foo']  # here index[0] is your first row & column is 'foo'
'A'

>>> df.loc[df.index[1], 'foo']
'B'
```

OR

```
>>> df.iloc[0]
foo    A
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

another example:

```
                              Region                            Nation        Item Type  Order Date   Order ID   Ship Date  Units Sold  U_Price  Total Cost
0               Australia and Oceania                            Tuvalu        Baby Food   5/28/2010  669165933   6/27/2010        9925   255.28  1582243.50
1   Central America and the Caribbean                           Grenada           Cereal   8/22/2012  963881480   9/15/2012        2804   205.70   328376.44
2                              Europe                            Russia  Office Supplies    5/2/2014  341417157    5/8/2014        1779   651.21   933903.84
3                  Sub-Saharan Africa             Sao Tome and Principe           Fruits   6/20/2014  514321792    7/5/2014        8102     9.33    56065.84
4                  Sub-Saharan Africa                            Rwanda  Office Supplies    2/1/2013  115456712    2/6/2013        5062   651.21  2657347.52
```

So you can code like below..

```
import pandas as pd
##################### Pandas Display Settings For Terminal #########
pd.set_option('display.height', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', True)
##################### END OF THE Display Settings ###################

df_csv = pd.read_csv("Sales-Records.csv")).fillna('')
df_trim = df_csv[['Region', 'Nation', 'Item Type','Order Date', 'Order ID','Ship Date', 'Units Sold', 'U_Price','Total Cost']]
print(df_trim.loc[df_trim.index[0], 'Nation'])
```

output

```
./test.py
Tuvalu
```

Comment: hey @pygo thanks for your answer and effort. i will check your code and let you know!